# How call function in renderer html with Ext.js 4.2

Tags: extjs

Code is:

```
Ext.define("Myapp", {
  extend: '',
  config: {},

  initComponent: function () {},

  getGrid: function () {
    Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
      ...
      columns: [
        {
          header: 'xx',
          renderer: function (value) {
            return '<a onclick=''>text</a>';
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  },

  test: function(){
    alert(1);
  },
});
```

In the above code, I want call test function in onclick event. I tried Myapp.test(), But it didn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can create global function inside some utility file then call this function as string only.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a listener to the cell and check inside the listener function if the user clicked the 'a' tag.

A good example has been made by [Tyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4066269/tyr)

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ods)

> ExtJS components working like simple object literals, so you can extend them with anything you want. In this case, i added the property "active" which can be checked in the beforeEdit listener.